# Why does this union organize data in a different way than expected?

Tags: c, i2c, spi

In the following code, I have a union with a struct and a uint32 (I am trying to convert from big-endian to little endian). I store a hex value in each of the bytes, and then I print the uint32 equivalent. I thought that structs order values in memory in the way that they are declared, but the output of this code is 0x302010 instead of the 0x102030 I expected. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
typedef union raw {
    struct {
       uint8_t LSB;
       uint8_t MID;
       uint8_t MSB;
    };
    uint32_t raw;
} raw;

int main()
{
    raw myraw;
    myraw.LSB = 0x10;
    myraw.MID = 0x20;
    myraw.MSB = 0x30;
    
    
    printf("%x", myraw.raw);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The bytes of the `uint32_t` are stored with the LSB first (on your system, this may vary)

Answer (score 0):

The names you gave the struct members is actually a hint as to what happened.

Your machine apparently used little endian byte ordering.  This means that multibyte types store the least significant byte first.  So the value you store in the `LSB` member is the least significant byte of the `raw` field.

However, note that not all 4 bytes of the `raw` field have corresponding fields in the inner struct.  That means that not all bytes of `raw` have been set, meaning that the value of the field as a whole is **indeterminate**.

You should add an additional field to the inner struct to match the bytes in `raw`.  You should also reverse the order of the fields if you want to switch between big endian and little endian.

```
typedef union raw {
    struct {
       uint8_t MSB;
       uint8_t MID1;
       uint8_t MID2;
       uint8_t LSB;
    };
    uint32_t raw;
} raw;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that structs order values in memory in the way that they are declared.

They *are.* Your problem is almost certainly because you're on a little-endian architecture where the most significant byte is the higher memory address.

So, the fact that you have them ordered `LSB, MID, MSB`, is actually the same way that would be in the `uint32_t` (except the `MSB` isn't the most significant byte of your `uint32_t`, just of the 24-bit value you're using).

If you want to *reverse* a big-endian value `0x00102030` with this method, you're going to need something like:

```
typedef union raw {
    struct {
       uint8_t MSB;
       uint8_t INR1;
       uint8_t INR2;
       uint8_t LSB;
    };
    uint32_t raw;
} raw;

myraw.MSB  = 0x00;
myraw.INR1 = 0x10;
myraw.INR2 = 0x20;
myraw.LSB  = 0x30;
```

Just keep in mind it's not always a good idea to read from a union field that *wasn't* the last one written to. C11 has this to say on the matter:

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called "type punning"). This might be a trap representation.

If you want something that's more portable, you can use a function along the lines of:

```
uint32_t reverseEndian(uint32_t input)
{
    return (input & 0x000000ffU) << 24 |
           (input & 0x0000ff00U) <<  8 |
           (input & 0x00ff0000U) >>  8 |
           (input & 0xff000000U) >> 24;
}
```